# Terminal Git Status showing different than Visual Studio status

Tags: github, terminal, version-control, visual-studio-2022

I've been at this for a couple of days and I can't figure this out.

When I run `git status` on my terminal, it's giving me a different result than what my visual studio 2022 shows me. I think this all started when i added git lfs to my repo using `brew` so it doesnt track the larger files i have.

For example, in my terminal, it's showing: [image]. Usually they show the same files always and never have an issue.

but then on the same branch in visual studio 2022, it's showing, it's showing this:

[image]

so far, I've tried:

1. Restarting my computer and visual studio(I had to try)
2. Using the sync button (next to the pushbutton) in visual studio.
3. Running `git remote update` on my terminal

I can't find anything else on SO to try.

Any and all help or direction is appreciated!

Comment: You can try removing the .git  folder and relink with the repo again.

Comment: check .gitignore file of visual studio, these file may mark as ignored in visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Check your `.gitattributes` files; since you added git lfs, it tracks the large file extensions with the `.gitattributes` file. That may be the reason why Visual Studio is not tracking those files, but your git terminal does.

Comment: What are they checking their `.gitattributes` file for? Can you [edit] your answer to provide additional detail?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug which i also face in visual studio.
Sometimes the VSCode cannot track the files which are updated.
what you can try is update the visual studio to see if the bug is fixed or not.

Mine was resolved by updating the VS.

PS: try using GitLens for a broader view of git.